# Почему мой цикл for ... in не работает правильно?

Tags: javascript, jquery, циклы

Я уже несколько часов ломаю себе голову, не могу понять почему мой код не работает правильно. В общем моя цель чтобы при клике на главной странице, менялся текст внутри тэга `<h1>`

[image: Пример]

Ранее я уже выполнил это простым способом как показано ниже, и конечно прописывал каждый класс элемента `.ottogi` `.sojo` `.natura` ну итд. Можно ссылаться по следующей ссылке http://test1.testkz.ru/

```
var text = $('.inner-container h1').text();
var changeString = $('.inner-container h1');

$('.ottogi').click(function() {
    if (text == 'Ottogi') {
        $(changeString).text('Ottogi');
    }
});
 $('.sajo').click(function() {
     if (text == 'Ottogi') {
        $(changeString).text('Sajo Hapyo');
    }
 });
```

Потом, чтобы не повторять данную процедуру 6 раз, решил создать объект, и пробижаться по нему циклом `for ... in` для реализации данной процедуры.
Возможно мой `if` не срабатывает правильно. Ребята посмотрите и помогите пожалуйста

```
const selectorToResponse = {
  '.ottogi': 'Ottogi',
  '.sajo': 'Sajo Hapyo',
  '.natura': 'Natura Bogata',
  '.maloo': 'TOO Maлy',
  '.dongush': 'Dongsuh',
  '.may': 'OOO Maй'
}

// Prefixing with $ to denote that is an element, not text etc
const $header = $('.inner-container h1')

for (const selector in selectorToResponse) {
  $(selector).click = function () {
    // using $header.text() inside function so that is current header text
    // `text` never changed in your example
    if ($header.text() === 'Ottogi') { // using === instead of ==
      const response = selectorToResponse[selector]

      $header.text(response)
    }
  }
}
```

Вот HTML

```
        <div class="left-main col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="shadow-effect"><p class="ottogi">OTTOGI</p></div>
            <div class="shadow-effect"><p class="sajo">Sajo Hapyo</p></div>
            <div class="shadow-effect"><p class="natura">Natura Bogata</p></div>
            <div class="shadow-effect"><p class="maloo">ТОО Малу</p></div>
            <div class="shadow-effect"><p class="dongush">Dongsuh</p></div>
            <div class="shadow-effect"><p class="may">ООО Май</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-main col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="inner-container">
                <h1>Ottogi</h1>
                <h2>Южно - Корейские продукты питания высочайшего качества!</h2>
            </div>
```

Comment: А что именно у вас не работает? У меня всё переключается. Вы в каком браузере проверяете? Ну кроме Safari, в Safari у меня и верства поехала...

Comment: @AlexanderBragin у вас работает потому му что на сайте используется старый скрипт который показан выше, сейчас я его отключу и можете посмотреть

Comment: сейчас посмотрю.

Comment: прошу прощение за долгий ответ. Пришлось инструмент перехвата трафика ставить, чтобы можно было прям на вашем сайте результат изменений смотреть. Написал в ответ. Это касаемо изменения заголовков. Посмотрите: такой вариант устроит? Не совсем понял для чего вы объект объявляли — что-то дальше предполагалось делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вместо**

```js
const selectorToResponse = {
  '.ottogi': 'Ottogi',
  '.sajo': 'Sajo Hapyo',
  '.natura': 'Natura Bogata',
  '.maloo': 'TOO Maлy',
  '.dongush': 'Dongsuh',
  '.may': 'OOO Maй'
}

// Prefixing with $ to denote that is an element, not text etc
const $header = $('.inner-container h1')

for (const selector in selectorToResponse) {
  $(selector).click = function () {
    // using $header.text() inside function so that is current header text
    // `text` never changed in your example
    if ($header.text() === 'Ottogi') { // using === instead of ==
      const response = selectorToResponse[selector]

      $header.text(response)
    }
  }
}
```

**Сократить код следующим образом**

Получаете значение из текста меню и выводите его в заголовок.

```js
$(function () {

    var header = $('.inner-container h1');

    $('.shadow-effect p').click(function () {
        header.text($(this).text());
    });

});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Такое простое решение! )

Comment: @nk-montreal пожалуйста! Будут ещё вопросы — задавайте.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//может вообще можно без объекта обойтись? зачем сущности плодить без надобности?
selectorToResponse.forEach(function (i){
  addEventListener("click", function(){
    if ($header.text() === 'Ottogi') { // using === instead of ==
      const response = selectorToResponse[selector]
      $header.text(response)
    }
  });
});
```

А зачем вы selector как константу объявляете? да еще внутри цикла?

Comment: така как значение констант не может быть изменено новым присваиванием, и не может быть переопределено. Хочу использовать правило хорошего тона так сказать. Здесь есть более подробное описание почему https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake

Comment: но в цикле же как раз происходит присваивание с каждой итерацией. Вы же скрипт не обманете))) Он понимает это так, константа - ее менять не надо берем массив и пытаемся изменить ... константу...(или я чего то не понимаю?) Попробуйте без констант обойтись